# Does using css sprite speed up performance in an html5 iphone app wrapped with phonegap?

Tags: iphone, css, html, cordova, css-sprites

I was wondering if creating a sprite for an HTML5 app, and wrapping it with phonegap for iPhone and Android, would increase performance at all. Because the app is offline, so it is only making a call for the image out of local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, no. However, at least on iOS, images aren't pre-loaded for each page load and you sometimes may see a 'flash' as the image is loaded into the page. So a sprite is one way to handle that. Another way is to use some JS to load all of your app's images in the background on the home page. It takes a bit longer for the app to load, but then everything is cached and ready to go.

Where sprites are a convenience, though, is maintenance. It's so much easier to only have to edit a handful of image sprites than it is to maintain dozens of individual image files.

Comment: is this the same for android?